# question about continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

everyone I have question can any one answer

prove that $f(x)= |x|$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$?
by using the definition of continuous.

Thank you

Comment: could you  tell me what is denoted by  this symbol  $\Re$??i can't recall it's name

Comment: by the  way  i think this function is not continuous because  $f(x)=x$  when $x>0$ and  $f(x)=-x$ when $x<0$

Comment: @dato: The absolute value function is continuous on $\Bbb R$, which is the more usual symbol for the real numbers.

Comment: yes i can't understand symbol itself

Comment: @leena adam  please see this link.http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage5/Lesson/Explain/contNotDiff.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if for every $ \epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
So take any $\epsilon >0$, let $\delta=\epsilon$ and suppose $|x-x_0| < \delta$. Then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| =||x|-|x_0|| \le |x-x_0| < \epsilon$, by the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $a\in\Bbb R$, if $|x-a|<\epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. In other words, with this function you can always choose $\delta$ in the definition of continuity to be equal to $\epsilon$.

Comment: yes using delta-epsilon notation absolutely correct,also  if $f(x)=|x|$  we are measuring in positive  area,then  by  definition of  limit we can also  conclude that it is continuous

Comment: ok i deleted my answer.i was thinking differently

Comment: thanks @Brian M.Scott i was confused with differentiated  condition .thanks

Comment: @dato: I thought that might be what happened. You’re welcome!

Comment: thank you all expert thanks

Comment: You’re welcome, @leena.